# Can I register even a small solar panel installation with my local renewable energy pool?

Tags: united-states, rebate

If I want to sell renewable energy credits and I have a small solar panel (just one, not a whole house system), can I still register my panel with the local renewable energy pool? My local pool is [NEPOOL](http://www.nepoolgis.com/how-to/account/). It is not clear from NEPOOL's documentation whether there is a statutory minimum a generator has to be to qualify for registration.

(Background for people who do not know what this is: people who generate renewable energy such as through wind power or solar power can register their generator with a "pool". Each region of the United States has a pool. The registrant can then sell energy "credits" according to how much energy the generator makes.)

Answer (score 1):

Contact the pool and ask. Be prepared to give them exact specs on your panel. Note that you will require an inverter specifically designed to connect safely to the grid, and your local electric company will have to be able/willing to set you up for net metering.

Comment: In my case I am using the energy only in my home, it is not getting put back on the grid.

Comment: @FiveBagger If you are not putting it back on the grid, then why would you get credits? The credits exist as payment that the utility company uses to provide electricity to others. It is not typically a government incentive, which would be more likely to come in the form of rebates on purchase / installation...

Comment: You may or may not be able to qualify for carbon credits without a grid connection.... But you'd have to install a pro-quality meter to report that production, and without net metering that may be hard to justify.